# Remote rendering WCM content using WSRP on IBM WebSphere Portal 7

Tags: websphere, portal, wcm, wsrp

We are using WebSphere Portal 7 and WCM 7 on seperate servers. We have set up WSRP so that we can render the WCM content on the Portal server. The problem I am having is that the recommended settings for the JSR 286 Web Content Viewer (to switch the dynamic link broadcasting featuire off) breaks the links on the rest of the page. If I switch the feature on, then the other links work but the links in the WCM content fail. All the local links (to other virtual portals, or mapped URLs) are rewritten (by Portal) to pass through the WsrpProxyPortlet, even though it is not necessary to do so.

Is there a way to use remote rendering on Portal 7 and WCM 7, so that one can use WCM and custom portlets on the same page and the links from, and to, either will both still work?

I put a table together of the permutations and the results of trying each, unfortunately it does not format correctly so I pasted it as formatted text.

```
+=======================================================================================================+
| Broadcast links to    | Receive links from    | Portal | WCM  | Comment                               |
+=======================================================================================================+
|                       | Other portlets and    | No     | Yes  | Portal links to the page with this    |
|                       | this portlet          |        |      | setting do not work                   |
| Dynamically select a  +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Web content page      | This portlet only     | Yes    | No   | WCM Links do not work at all          |
|                       +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       | None                  | Yes    | No   | WCM Links do not work at all          |
+=======================================================================================================+
|                       | Other portlets and    | No     | Yes  | Portal links to the page with this    |
|                       | this portlet          |        |      | setting do not work                   |
| This portal page      +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       | This portlet only     | Yes    | No   | WCM Links do not work at all          |
|                       +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       | None                  | Yes    | No   | WCM Links do not work at all          |
+=======================================================================================================+
|                       | Other portlets and    | No     | Yes* | Portal links to this page do not work.|
|                       | this portlet          |        |      | WCM and Portal links on this page     |
|                       |                       |        |      | works, once you get to it.            |
| The following portal  +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| page                  | This portlet only     | Yes    | No   | WCM Links do not work at all          |
|                       +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       | None                  | No*    | No   | Portal links only work if in the      |
|                       |                       |        |      | same context                          |
+=======================================================================================================+
|                       | Other portlets and    | No*    | No*  | Neither Portal, nor WCM, links to the |
|                       | this portlet          |        |      | page work as they should. You can     |
|                       |                       |        |      | only get to the page through a        |
|                       |                       |        |      | sequence of other pages. Once you get |
|                       |                       |        |      | to it WCM links work, but links to    |
| None                  |                       |        |      | other Portal pages break.             |
|                       +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       | This portlet only     | No     | No   | No way to get to this page.           |
|                       +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       | None                  | No*    | No   | Portal links to the page work, but    |
|                       |                       |        |      | links from the page do not.           |
+=======================================================================================================+
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Point your browser to the WCM server, at path /wps/wcm/myconnect/WCM-library/content-path/. Get example paths by previewing content items. Remote rendering is just asking that servlet for content, using http client and passing the LTPA cookie. You can also quickly rewrite the links to be parameters to your portlets (or other portlets - on other portal pages) - on the fly.

That's how IBM used to implement the official remote rendering portlet (available still at least on 6.1), and it's quite easy to build yourself if you can't find the actual non-wsrp remote rendering portlet anymore.

Comment: I don't have a issue getting content to render. I'm using the WSRP (LTPA tokens are set up) to render content from a WCM7 server on Portal7 using the JSR286 Web Content Viewer (IBM recommended setup, for Portal/WCM 7). The problem is that either WCM or Portal links break depending on the settings. Perhaps I'm missing something in what you are saying, if so please elucidate.

Comment: I see where you are going with this, I had hoped not to have to write our own remote content rendering portlet.